# Removing specific address from ReplyAll in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

EDITED

I wrote macro that finds an e-mail in shared mailbox and then replies to it. The problem is that for some cases I would like to remove my address (shared@mailbox) or some other and I don't know how to do it. I tried some methods that I found but none worked. Sorry for such a basic question.

```
    Const olFolderInbox = 6

    Sub Reminder()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient


    Set Outl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNamespace = Outl.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("shared@inbox")


    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objInbox = objNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderInbox)

    strFolderName = objInbox.Parent

    Set objMailbox = objNamespace.Folders(strFolderName)
    Set objFolder = objMailbox.Folders("Inbox").Folders("AAA").Folders("BBB")

    Set colItems = objFolder.Items

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder


    i = 1
    For Each olMail In objFolder.Items





      If olMail.Subject = "AAA" + ActiveSheet.Range("D" & (ActiveCell.Row)) Then

      Set oReplyAll = olMail.ReplyAll

       oReplyAll.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt;  font-family:Arial>Dear ,<br />  <br />" _
      & "Could you please remind the client to do something?<br />" _
      & "Thank you in advance.<br />" _
      <br /> </BODY>" _
       & oReplyAll.HTMLBody

      oReplyAll.CC = "xyz@xyz"

  '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  'EDIT
  '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    For j = 1 To oReplyAll.Recipients.Count
        With oReplyAll.Recipients(j)

        If .Name = "aaa@bbb" Then
           .Delete
            j = j - 1
    End If

    End With

    Next j


      oReplyAll.Display


    i = i + 1

        End If

    Next olMail


    End Sub
```

Edit: I've added loop iSpain17 wrote3 in a comment. Nothing changed. Reply displays normally with recipient in "To:" part although he should be removed

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next' permanently. Used at the start of the code it masks all errors. Almost guarantees failure and you cannot debug the code. Avoid using this until you know how. Update question with  any error you cannot resolve yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. However in this case deleting "On Error Resume Next" line did not change anything. There is no error, reply displays but still with the recipient that should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

There is a high probability that the text you want to match is not what you think it is.

Remove `On Error Resume Next` so you can fix any errors in this untested code.

With this structure you can delete/move more than one match as the index is not corrupted.

```
For j = oReplyAll.Recipients.Count to 1 step -1

    With oReplyAll.Recipients(j)

        debug.print "text to match " & .name

        If .Name = "text to match" Then
            .Delete
        End If

    End With

Next j
```

With this structure you can delete/move one match reliably.

```
For j = 1 To oReplyAll.Recipients.Count

    With oReplyAll.Recipients(j)

        debug.print "text to match " & .name

        If .Name = "text to match" Then
            .Delete

            ' exit now,
            ' else next item is skipped,
            ' as it moves up into the position of the deleted item
            exit for 

        End If

    End With

Next j
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: Please note, that when you use the Recipients.Add method, you set the Name property of your item. Thus, when you use for loop, you'll have to test against the Name property. Also, deleting an item modifies all other item's index, thus the *i=i-1*. I tried this, it worked for me.

```
For i = 1 To email.Recipients.Count

    With email.Recipients(i)

        If .Name = "address" Then
            .Delete
            i = i - 1
        End If

    End With

Next i
```

This loops through each recipient in the recipients, and if they match the given emailmaddress they are removed from the recipients.

This might not be the exact answer as i am not too familiar with outlook vba, but this is the logic i would use.

Comment: I tried something similar before. It does not work although it makes sense.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you exactly did and why it didn't work? What did it do or what kind of error you got?